# How can I prevent query string manipulation by user?

Tags: javascript, html-email, salesforce-marketing-cloud

Starting from an email created in Salesforce, I want to pass the user data in query string.
How can I avoid losing the values in the query string if the user decides to delete it and reload the page?
Is there a method in Javascript or other programmatic language that I can use in Landing Page?

Comment: impossible.....

Comment: Just a thought. How about passing it to first page, store and redirect to where users are supposed to go. This might help. If your string is encrypted then there might be less chances of it being edited/changed.